# How do I call LocalFree()?

Tags: c, winapi

I have this piece of code

```
HLOCAL localHandle;
char *lpText;
localHandle = LocalAlloc(LMEM_MOVEABLE, 40);
if(localHandle)
{
    lpText = (char*)LocalLock(localHandle);
    //Call LocalFree(localHandle) or LocalFree(lpText) ????
}
```

Should I call `LocalFree(localHandle);` or `LocalFree(lpText);` ?

Comment: Note that (unless you have to support *very* old versions of Windows) Microsoft strongly recommend that you use the [Heap Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of LocalAlloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those, but never LocalFree(lpText)  From the looks of your code, the memory pointed to by lpText is going to be junk after you call LocalFree.

If you call LocalLock, then you should call LocalUnlock(localHandle) before you call LocalFree(localHandle).

Why not just use malloc? Is there some technical reason you need to only call LocalAlloc?  Let the runtime do the work for you.

Comment: I chose this as best answer because he said "but never LocalFree(lpText)" which made things very clear

Comment: One reason why you might want to avoid malloc() is that it means you have to call free() *from the same instance of the C runtime library*, which can be inconvenient in some contexts - though if you're following best practice, the same source file that calls malloc() will be calling free() and everything will be fine.  Another reason is if you don't want the overhead of linking with the C runtime library at all.

Answer (score 3):

The `hMem` parameter for [LocalFree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366730.aspx) is documented as:

> A handle to the local memory object. This handle is returned by either the [**LocalAlloc**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366723.aspx) or [**LocalReAlloc**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366742.aspx) function. It is not safe to free memory allocated with [**GlobalAlloc**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366574.aspx).

So in your sample you need to call:

```
LocalFree(localHandle);
```

Don't forget to call [LocalUnlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366747.aspx) before calling [LocalFree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366730.aspx), to decrement the reference count. This is mandatory when using `LMEM_MOVEABLE`.

Comment: Do I call LocalUnlock(localHandle) or LocalUnlock(lpText) ?

Comment: As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366747.aspx) says: *"A handle to the local memory object. This handle is returned by either the [**LocalAlloc**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366723.aspx) or [**LocalReAlloc**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366742.aspx) function."*

Answer (score 1):

These functions seem to be part of some library. I don't know the library, but usually (see malloc() and free()), you have to call the free()-function on the pointer/object returned by the malloc()-function.

So in your case that would be `LocalFree(localHandle)`.

Comment: The "library" in this case would be the Windows API. :-)